# ActionScript 3.0 Document class getting stage as null

Tags: actionscript-3, null, movieclip, stage, document-class

My Document class is not extending to movie clip class. It is getting stage reference as null.
Please help me to get me out of this.
Thanks in advance.

**Code for Document Class:**

```
package 
{
    import com.andreanaya.areacontrol.Container;
    import paperwings.display.area.Build;
    import paperwings.display.components.generic.TopMenu;
    import paperwings.webservices.analytics.Tracker;

    public class PaperWings extends Container 
    {
        private var _build : Build;
        private var _menu : TopMenu;
        public function PaperWings():void 
        {
            super();
            init();
        }


        override public function init() : void 
        {
            SWFWheel.initialize(stage);
            this._build = new Build();
            this._menu = new TopMenu();
            addChild(this._menu);
            this._menu.show(0.5);

            addChild(this._build);
            this._build.init();
            super.init();

        } 

    }

}
```

**Code for Inherited class :** This is class from which main class is inherited..

```
    package com.andreanaya.areacontrol
{
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.display.Stage;
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
   import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;


   public class Container extends Sprite
   {

      public function Container() {
         super();
         trace("construcor.. Container.")
         this._paths = new Array();
         this._containers = new Array();
         this._content = new Array();
         addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.SHOW,this.onChange);
         addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.HIDE,this.onChange);
         addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.UPDATE,this.onChange);
      }

      private var _paths:Array;

      private var _containers:Array;

      private var _content:Array;

      private var _container:Container;

      private var _className:String;

      private var _status:String = "hide";

      private var _changes:int;

      private var _pathNames:Array;

      private var _param:Object;

      override public function get stage() : Stage {
         return AreaControl.stage;
      }

      public function init() : void {
          trace("container init ");
         dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.INIT));
      }

      public function show(param1:Array=null, param2:Object=null) : void {
         dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.SHOW));
      }

      public function hide() : void {
         dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.HIDE));
      }

      public function update(param1:Array=null, param2:Object=null) : void {
         dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.UPDATE));
      }

      public function preload(param1:Array=null, param2:Object=null) : void {
         dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.PRELOAD));
      }

      override public function addChild(param1:DisplayObject) : DisplayObject {
         var _loc2_:uint = 0;
         if(param1  is  Container)
         {
            _loc2_ = this._containers.length;
            while(--_loc2_ > -1)
            {
               if(this._containers[_loc2_] == param1)
               {
                  return super.addChild(param1);
               }
            }
            param1.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.onChange);
            this._containers.push(param1);
         }
         return super.addChild(param1);
      }

      override public function addChildAt(param1:DisplayObject, param2:int) : DisplayObject {
         var _loc3_:uint = 0;
         if(param1  is  Container)
         {
            _loc3_ = this._containers.length;
            while(--_loc3_ > -1)
            {
               if(this._containers[_loc3_] == param1)
               {
                  return super.addChildAt(param1,param2);
               }
            }
            param1.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.onChange);
            this._containers.push(param1);
         }
         return super.addChildAt(param1,param2);
      }

      override public function removeChild(param1:DisplayObject) : DisplayObject {
         var _loc2_:uint = 0;
         if(param1  is  Container)
         {
            _loc2_ = this._containers.length;
            while(--_loc2_ > -1)
            {
               if(this._containers[_loc2_] == param1)
               {
                  this._containers.splice(_loc2_,1);
                  return super.removeChild(param1);
               }
            }
            this._containers.push(param1);
         }
         return super.removeChild(param1);
      }

      override public function removeChildAt(param1:int) : DisplayObject {
         var _loc3_:uint = 0;
         var _loc2_:DisplayObject = super.removeChildAt(param1);
         if(_loc2_  is  Container)
         {
            _loc3_ = this._containers.length;
            while(--_loc3_ > -1)
            {
               if(this._containers[_loc3_] == _loc2_)
               {
                  this._containers.splice(_loc3_,1);
                  return _loc2_;
               }
            }
         }
         return _loc2_;
      }

      public function addPath(param1:String, param2:String=null) : void {
         var _loc3_:uint = this._paths.length;
         while(--_loc3_ > -1)
         {
            if(this._paths[_loc3_].pathName == param1)
            {
               this._paths[_loc3_].className = param2;
               return;
            }
         }
         this._paths.push(
            {
               "pathName":param1,
               "className":param2
            }
         );
      }

      public function removePath(param1:String) : void {
         var _loc2_:uint = this._paths.length;
         while(--_loc2_ > -1)
         {
            if(this._paths[_loc2_].pathName == param1)
            {
               this._paths.splice(_loc2_,1);
               return;
            }
         }
      }

      private function checkPath(param1:String) : Object {
         var _loc2_:uint = this._paths.length;
         while(--_loc2_ > -1)
         {
            if(this._paths[_loc2_].pathName == "*" || this._paths[_loc2_].pathName == param1)
            {
               return this._paths[_loc2_];
            }
         }
         return null;
      }

      private function createContent(param1:String) : Container {
         var _loc2_:uint = this._content.length;
         while(--_loc2_ > -1)
         {
            if(this._content[_loc2_].className == param1)
            {
               this._content[_loc2_].container.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.onChange);
               this._content[_loc2_].container.change(this._pathNames,this._param);
               super.addChildAt(this._content[_loc2_].container,0);
               return this._content[_loc2_].container;
            }
         }
         var _loc3_:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(param1) as Class;
         var _loc4_:Container = new _loc3_();
         _loc4_.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.INIT,this.onInit);
         _loc4_.init();
         this._content.push(
            {
               "className":param1,
               "container":_loc4_
            }
         );
         return _loc4_;
      }

      function check(param1:Array=null) : Boolean {
         var _loc2_:uint = 0;
         if(!param1 || this._paths.length == 0)
         {
            return false;
         }
         if(param1.length > 0)
         {
            _loc2_ = this._paths.length;
            while(--_loc2_ > -1)
            {
               if(this._paths[_loc2_].pathName == "*")
               {
                  return false;
               }
               if(this._paths[_loc2_].pathName == param1[0])
               {
                  return true;
               }
            }
         }
         if((this._container) && (this._container.check(param1)))
         {
            return true;
         }
         var _loc3_:Array = param1.concat();
         _loc3_.splice(0,1);
         _loc2_ = this._containers.length;
         while(--_loc2_ > -1)
         {
            if(this._containers[_loc2_].check(_loc3_))
            {
               return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
      }

      function change(param1:Array=null, param2:Object=null) : void {
         if(!param1 || this._paths.length == 0)
         {
            dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE));
            return;
         }
         this._pathNames = param1;
         this._param = param2;
         var _loc3_:Object = param1.length > 0?this.checkPath(param1[0]):null;
         this._changes = 0;
         if(_loc3_)
         {
            if(this._status == "show")
            {
               this._status = "update";
            }
            else
            {
               this._status = "show";
            }
            this._changes++;
            addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.PRELOAD,this.onPreload);
            this.preload(param1,param2);
         }
         else
         {
            if(this._status == "show")
            {
               this._changes++;
               this._status = "hide";
               if(this._container)
               {
                  this._changes++;
                  this._container.change([]);
               }
               this.changeChildren([]);
               if(this._changes == 1)
               {
                  this.hide();
               }
            }
            else
            {
               dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE));
               return;
            }
         }
      }

      private function onPreload(param1:AreaControlEvent) : void {
         var _loc2_:Object = this._pathNames.length > 0?this.checkPath(this._pathNames[0]):null;
         if(_loc2_.className)
         {
            if(this._container)
            {
               if(this._className == _loc2_.className)
               {
                  this._changes++;
                  this._container.change(this._pathNames,this._param);
               }
               else
               {
                  this._changes++;
                  this._container.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.removeContent);
                  this._container.change(this._pathNames,this._param);
                  this._changes++;
                  this._container = this.createContent(_loc2_.className);
               }
            }
            else
            {
               this._changes++;
               this._container = this.createContent(_loc2_.className);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            if(this._container)
            {
               this._changes++;
               this._container.change(this._pathNames,this._param);
            }
         }
         this._className = _loc2_.className;
         var _loc3_:Array = this._pathNames.concat();
         _loc3_.splice(0,1);
         this.changeChildren(_loc3_,this._param);
         if(this._status == "show")
         {
            this.show(this._pathNames,this._param);
         }
         else
         {
            if(this._status == "update")
            {
               this._status = "show";
               this.update(this._pathNames,this._param);
            }
         }
      }

      private function changeChildren(param1:Array=null, param2:Object=null) : void {
         var _loc3_:uint = this._containers.length;
         while(--_loc3_ > -1)
         {
            this._changes++;
            this._containers[_loc3_].change(param1,param2);
         }
      }

      private function onInit(param1:AreaControlEvent) : void {
         this._container = param1.currentTarget as Container;
         super.addChildAt(this._container,0);
         this._container.removeEventListener(AreaControlEvent.INIT,this.onInit);
         this._container.addPath(this._pathNames[0]);
         this._container.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.onChange);
         this._container.change(this._pathNames,this._param);
      }

      private function removeContent(param1:AreaControlEvent) : void {
         param1.currentTarget.addEventListener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.onChange);
         param1.currentTarget.removeEventLisntener(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE,this.removeContent);
         super.removeChild(param1.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
      }

      private function onChange(param1:AreaControlEvent) : void {
         trace("on change"+this._changes)
         this._changes--;
         if(this._changes == 0)
         {
            this.dispatchEvent(new AreaControlEvent(AreaControlEvent.CHANGE));
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a common sense of accessing your *stage* after the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event fired. Like this (I'll just edit your existing code)

```
public class PaperWings extends Container 
{
    private var _build : Build;
    private var _menu : TopMenu;
    public function PaperWings():void 
    {
        super();
        //PROBLEM HERE
        //If you call init with your stage == null,
        //it will throw an error when you are initializing your SWFWheel lib
        init();
    }

    override public function init() : void 
    {
        //ERROR HERE
        SWFWheel.initialize(stage);
        //=========================
        this._build = new Build();
        this._menu = new TopMenu();
        addChild(this._menu);
        this._menu.show(0.5);

        addChild(this._build);
        this._build.init();
        super.init();

    } 
....
```

So you just edit it as I've shown you - it will most likely solve your problem

```
public class PaperWings extends Container 
{
    private var _build : Build;
    private var _menu : TopMenu;
    public function PaperWings():void 
    {
        super();
        //We check our stage reference first, so we won't get any error
        if(stage)
            init();
        else
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    override public function init(e:Event = null) : void 
    {
        //stage is never null here.
        SWFWheel.initialize(stage);
        this._build = new Build();
        this._menu = new TopMenu();
        addChild(this._menu);
        this._menu.show(0.5);

        addChild(this._build);
        this._build.init();
        super.init();

    }
```

And btw, I'd suggest you using [this](https://github.com/KumoKairo/BlastedMouseWheelBlock) lib to block browser scroll instead. It's more lightweight and well optimized ;)

Comment: I am able to add display objects The only problem here is that I am getting stage as null.. The class from which my document class is inherited is extending sprite.. Help me

Comment: Please, provide more code then. Where do you check your stage link? I've updated my answer, take a look

Comment: You didn't provide any. Please paste something)

Comment: Ok Please let me know about pasting AS 3.0 code, I am getting formatting error

Comment: If you can share a small demo project, I will be able to have a look at it.